# get data from protocol buffer response into img src

Tags: javascript, html, protocol-buffers

i have a code which calls an image via URL. 
Now the URL returns a protocol buffer, when i open the link separately in a new tab it shows text  " **["imagename",[[null,null,"data:image/jpeg;charset;utf-8;base64,#encoded#"]]]"** 
since  the URL returns a text response, is there any way i can get the whole response into a string(10K+ characters) and then i can slice it and put it in the img src.
i just want to put the whole code into single html file or is there a way to write proto schema inside the html code and then retrieve data from it. (I have just started with programming)

```
//Html
<img id="image" Src="#URL">
//javascript
var imgstring=document.getElementById("image");
//when i print this, I get it as "[object HTML ImageElement]"
//if i use the .value it gives the output as "undefined"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would like to help you:

```
var byteArray = new Uint8Array(#Buffer Data#);
var blob = new Blob([byteArray]);
const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```